# Школьное расписание на дни недели

Tags: pascal

Нужно написать программу на Pascal: как определить по дате (число.месяц.год) день недели? Т.е. вводите дату, а должно вывести номер дня недели. Эта программа послужит процедурой для более сложной программы.

Comment: Не изобретайте велосипед... Используйте возможности языка программирования

Comment: Точное определение (с учетом особенностей перехода на летнее/зимнее время в конкретном регионе или даже изменением календаря (РСФСР 1918 год)) для произвольной даты (например много лет назад) может быть весьма сложным.

Хотя, судя по названию вопроса, этот комментарий носит теоретический характер.

Comment: а как переход на зимнее/летнее время может повлиять на определение дня недели по дате.месяцу.году ?

Comment: видимо @avp имеет ввиду определение по timestamp'у...

Если теоретически - у меня есть доступ к арифметическому ( + округление ) выводу, правда без учёта и половины подводных камней, дня недели из гггг/мм/дд

Comment: в общем, вопрос слишком общий. нужно автору задать его более конкретно: какой язык он использует и т.д.

Comment: А разве процедуры могут возвращать значение?

Comment: @mikillskegg, Вы правы, нечего ночью пялиться на терминал, спать надо.

Вообще комментарий навеян воспоминаниями о UTC и выходных днях в разных аэропортах.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну смотря на каком языке программируете и возможно эти данные необходимо получить из бд. А вообще переводят дату а юникстаймстамп и далее получают то чего Вы и хотите. Если СУБД то у него есть огромные возможности для работы со временем и датой, можно уже выдернуть с базы данные в нужным Вам виде.

Answer (score 0):

Например, [здесь](http://www.hardforum.ru/t62203/)

Однако, соглашусь с [[@timka_s](/users/1192/timka_s)](/users/1192/timka_s): лучше использовать стандартные средства для работы со временем, предоставляемые применяемым языком.

**Продолжение банкета.**

Я вот не знаю Паскаль, и то  погуглил и сразу нашел [сайт](http://wm-help.net/books-online/book/1492/1492-10.html)

`Function EncodeDate(Year, Moth, Day: Word): TDateTime;` - создает переменную типа дата по дню-месяцу-году

`Function DayOfWeek(Date: TDateTime): Integer;` - вычисляет день недели по дате